# TLS Version for .net Core 2.2 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

For an api that used the .Net Framework I was able to use the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to see the SSL/TLS protocol that was currently enabled for that application.
In a .net core 2.2 web api, when I use the HttpClient I can see that the SslProtocols property for the HttpClientHandler is set to SystemDefault, but when I make a request to https://www.howsmyssl.com it tells me that I'm using TLS1.2. Is it possible to get the currently enabled TLS version that will be used with the HttpClient?

Comment: Microsoft has all explanations in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls So `SystemDefault` is what you might use (delegate the version selection to Windows, or other OS). Pros and cons are all there.

Comment: Why the downvote?